# Troubles with importing data into R

Tags: r, import

I know it is a basic question and I have been looking for a specific answer for months.

Here is the deal:
Every time that I try to import tables to R, there is a problem and they never get imported properly. I have done this with my own files and with files that I got from courses. I have tried putting comas, semicolons, I have used the (header=TRUE, 
    sep=",", row.names="id")
But it just won't work.

Here is what I mean. I am really getting desperate with being unable to complete this very simple task that prevents me to go on with the actual analysis.
Thank you very much in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFUeD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y94GJ.png)

Comment: It looks like the data in question is semicolon separated, not comma separated.  Ensure that your data is in fact saved as comma separated values before trying to import it using `read.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lke the first comment says, the problem is the separator. You can try

```
fread(file_name, sep = ";") # data.table package
read.csv(file_name, sep = ";") # utils package
```

It could be that you're importing European .csv files or that your Excel is set to some other language. You may also want to check on the decimal separator `dec = ","` which is common for European .csv files.